# number of neurons in the output layer of a competitive learning ANN

Tags: machine-learning, unsupervised-learning

How to determine the number of neurons in the output layer of a competitive learning ANN?

Does the value depend on how many classes that we need to predict?

Answer (score 6):

Yes. It depends on the number of class we wish to identify. For example, if you want to predict whether survived or not based on age, gender, and others features. Then in your Artificial Neural Network, the number of output layer nodes will be 2 (survive or not).
[image: collected from internet]